# VMWare Workstation 8 reporting ""vmx86 driver version invalid handle" problem on booting VM

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

I'm just doing a VMWare Workstation 8 installation. However, on trying to boot (or create) a VM, it's reporting "Could not get vmx86 driver version: The handle is invalid."

It recommends reinstalling, which I've done.

Also, VMWare Player just hangs.

Was going to post on the VMWare forums, but can't seem to create a new discussion (even though I've registered/logged in).

It's our own fault for being too eager to upgrade, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

just run VMware workstation/player as administrator and you won't get this error.

Comment: Yes, running VMware as asministrator fixed my issue.